# unidentifed offset errors php

Tags: php, error-handling

I made a simple quiz scoring using PHP but its coming up with unidentifed offset errors, but it works fine.

errors:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\Users\scorequiz1.php on line 17
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\Users\scorequiz1.php on line 18
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\Users\scorequiz1.php on line 19
Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\Users\scorequiz1.php on line 20
Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in C:\Users\scorequiz1.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\Users\scorequiz1.php on line 52
Question 1. Correct.

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\Users\scorequiz1.php on line 52
Question 2. Incorrect.

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\Users\scorequiz1.php on line 52
Question 3. Correct.

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\Users\scorequiz1.php on line 52
Question 4. Correct.

Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in C:\Users\scorequiz1.php on line 52
Question 5. Incorrect.
```

line 17 to 21:

```
$data[0] = $_POST["a"];
$data[1] = $_POST["b"];
$data[2] = $_POST["c"];
$data[3] = $_POST["d"];
$data[4] = $_POST["e"];
```

line 50-56:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
{
     if($answer[$i] == 1)
         echo "Question " . ($i+1) . ". " . "Correct.<br/>";
     else
         echo "Question " . ($i+1) . ". " . "Incorrect.<br/>";
}
```

my quiz is just like this. The options for question has the name "a" to "e" and the value to check for the right answer

```
<!-- question 1---->
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="a" VALUE="1">10 days<BR>
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="a" VALUE="1">40 days<BR>

<!-- question 2---->
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="b" VALUE="1">True<BR>
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="b" VALUE="1">False<BR>
```

I'm not sure whats wrong

Comment: "Unidentified" !== "undefined".

Comment: I can only assume that the $data array was used somewhere else and is somehow in scope when you attempt to set the values manually setting the numeric indexes. My assumption is that your version of PHP is first checking if the value exists in that array in case it needs to overwrite the value. You would probably eliminate that error by resetting it by doing $data = array() before u set the values. I would need a bit more info to figure out what's up with $answers though.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely issue for the first half is that `$data` might already be set to something else. Try this:

```
$data = Array($_POST['a'],$_POST['b']...);
```

For the second half, are you sure you defined `$answer` correctly? It looks like you meant `$data` there.

Side-note: I can instantly get a perfect score on your test with this:

```
(function() {
    var qsa = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]"), l = qsa.length, i;
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) if( qsa[i].value == "1") qsa[i].checked = true;
})();
```

Just stick that in the console and the test will automatically be filled out with the correct answers.

Comment: $answers[] is an array to keep track of the questions the the user got right. at the start it gets initalized to 0 then i use IF statements to see if the user gets it right     if($data[0]=="2"){$answer[0] = 1; $points++; "

Comment: @Kolink - If `VALUE="1"` on all of the questions, how would your js function work?

Answer (score 0):

try validate values first before referring them in array
I usually use empty to check first, so in your case only continue running the codes if they are not empty

```
    if (!empty($data[0])) 
    if (!empty($answer[$i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

you code looks to have two possible problems

1. You are setting value to `$data` variables and using `$answer` variable to check the correctness. If two variables are intentional, means you must be checking it with some database and creating `$answer` array elsewhere that you have not shown - share that code too.
2. The sample HTML you shared has `value="1"` written to all options of the question.. if that is exactly how you have in the code, means you will get 1 even if any answer is picked.